# How to know while user editing the WPF DataGrid Cell is empty?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `WPF` `DataGrid`. The users can edit the data in `cell`. I want a `event` in that I want to check if `cell` is `empty`. User can empty the data by using `Del` `Backspace` `Cut` options etc.

Give me a `event` and `event handler` to do that. I already tries `OnCellEditEnding` `event` but this will trigger only if edit is finished. I want to check `cell` is empty dynamically each time when user `inputs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

each datagridcell has a textbox as its content when it is in the edit mode. you can check the text Length written in that textbox whenever a key is down (by handling *onKeyDown* or *onPreviewKeyDown* event)

edit:

use PreparingCellForEdit event, sth like this:

```
void MainDataGrid_PreparingCellForEdit(object sender, DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs e)
{
   TextBox tb = e.Column.GetCellContent(e.Row) as TextBox;
   tb.TextChanged+=new TextChangedEventHandler(tb_TextChanged); 
}

void tb_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
   //here, something changed the cell's text. you can do what is neccesary
}
```

Comment: This is false assumption, see `DataGridTemplateColumn`.

Comment: You are right, but I think WPFK is dealing with a DataGridTextColumn.

Comment: Guys! What if I right on and cut the all data when is on edit mode?
How do  I trigger the OS cut commands?

Answer (score 2):

Use [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612.aspx):

```
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

where items source is a sequence of objects like this:

```
public class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                // oops!
            }

            if (firstName != value)
            {
                firstName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FirstName"); // raises INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
            }
        }
    }
    private string firstName;

    public string LastName { /* ... */}
}
```