# How to allow to enter only after decimal 2 value in DataGridTextColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Is there a way to enter only after decimal 2 value in DatagridTextbox column and also restrict the user to enter only one decimal point?

I mean to achieve that a user can only enter something like `1234.25`, not `1234.1234`, and also prevent them from entering something like this `1234.235.2`

Comment: What is a _after decimal 2 value_? Can you show an example for allowed and for not allowed values?

Comment: I mean to say that user can only enter like 1234.25 not 1234.1234 and user also restrict on to enter 1234.235.2 like this

Answer (score 0):

Use the String Format property on the value you are binding too:

```
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total Cost" Binding="{Binding Path=Total, StringFormat={}{0:N2}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this question and the answer: [How to know while user editing the WPF DataGrid Cell is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466889/how-to-know-while-user-editing-the-wpf-datagrid-cell-is-empty/13467131#13467131)

you should handle TextChanged event too, and your code should be sth like this:

```
void tb_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
   TextBox tb=(TextBox)sender;
   tb.Forground = Brushes.Black;
   int indexOfDot=tb.Text.IndexOf(".");
   if (indexOfDot != -1)
      {
          if (tb.Text.Length>indexOfDot+2)
          {
              //here you can tell the user that this is a wrong format
              //and do other stuff; for example:
              tb.Forground = Brushes.Red;
          }
      }
}
```

If you want the user not to be able to type a wrong format, then handle OnPreviewKeyDown event. you can set some other conditions. If you want it to be a double, then try this:

```
double d;
if (double.TryParse(tb.Text,out d) == false)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```