# Finding a TextBox in a DataGridCell's CellEditingTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a problem in WPF of programatically accessing a textbox in a DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate, when the cell is selected and in editing mode.

Here is the XAML of my DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="OrderLinesGrid"
          Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          SelectionUnit="Cell"
          ItemsSource="{Binding OrderLines}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="NumberColumn"
                            Header="Varenr."
                            MinWidth="100">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBox Text="{Binding Number}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

How can I access that TextBox when the cell is selected? Here is a image showing the visual tree of the DataGrid if that can help you:

[image: DataGrid Visual Tree]

I have tried the following in a DataGridCell GotFocus event, but without luck. It simply returns NULL because it is not found.

```
private void DataGridCellGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var cell = sender as DataGridCell;
    var textBox = FindChild<TextBox>(cell, null);
}
```

Where the FindChild method is the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// Finds a Child of a given item in the visual tree. 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="parent">A direct parent of the queried item.</param>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the queried item.</typeparam>
/// <param name="childName">x:Name or Name of child. </param>
/// <returns>The first parent item that matches the submitted type parameter. 
/// If not matching item can be found, 
/// a null parent is being returned.</returns>
public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName)
    where T : DependencyObject
{
    // Confirm parent and childName are valid. 
    if (parent == null) return null;

    T foundChild = null;

    int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        // If the child is not of the request child type child
        T childType = child as T;
        if (childType == null)
        {
            // recursively drill down the tree
            foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

            // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
            if (foundChild != null) break;
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
        {
            var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
            // If the child's name is set for search
            if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
            {
                // if the child's name is of the request name
                foundChild = (T)child;
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // child element found.
            foundChild = (T)child;
            break;
        }
    }

    return foundChild;
}
```

I suspect it has something to do with the DataTemplate but I need some suggestions on how to select the TextBox child element?

Comment: what you want to do with that editor? what is your goal?

Comment: For one thing, I need to give focus to the textbox (and other controls) when the DataGridCell is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you you should avoid using `VisualTreeHelper` as much as possible. If i understood, you can encapsulate your login within `CellEditingCommand`

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Number}">
      <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
          <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CellEditingCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
      </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
  </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

Also you can use [Behaviors](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/401707/Behavior-and-Trigger-in-WPF-Silverlight)

**UPD**:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Number}">
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
            <Interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                <TriggerActions:TakeFocusAction />
            </Interactivity:EventTrigger>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

and trigger action

```
public class TakeFocusAction : TriggerAction<UIElement>
{
    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        AssociatedObject.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: My problem is that I need to select the textbox programatically when the cell receives focus (i.e. is clicked).

Comment: u can write behavior for this

Comment: Your solution triggers when the TextBox receives focus, not the DataGridCell. It is the DataGridCell that receives focus, and in the DataGridCell's GotFocus event handler, I need to select the TextBox programatically.

Comment: if you simply want set focus on textbox when cell begin editing, see UPD

Comment: Beautiful solution for my focus problem. And thank you very much for that! However, I would still like to know how I can access that TextBox programatically. But this solved one of my problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
ContentPresenter presenter = e.Column.GetCellContent(e.Row);    
TextBox textBox = presenter.ContentTemplate.FindName("nameOfYourTextBox", presenter) as TextBox;
```

Comment: Could you leave at least a short note to the code (what's the key method, why is it working?)

Comment: I use similar code to open the combobox when I click on the cell:
        `private void CurrentCellChanged(object s, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (grid.CurrentColumn == column)
            {
                if (grid.BeginEdit())
                {
                    var element = column.GetCellContent(grid.CurrentCell.Item);
                    //DataGridComboBoxColumn
                    if (element is ComboBox)
                    {
                        (element as ComboBox).IsDropDownOpen = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should handle `PreparingCellForEdit`: Sth

```
void MainDataGrid_PreparingCellForEdit(object sender, DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs e)
{
   TextBox tb = e.Column.GetCellContent(e.Row) as TextBox;
}
```

See: [How to know while user editing the WPF DataGrid Cell is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466889/how-to-know-while-user-editing-the-wpf-datagrid-cell-is-empty/13467131#13467131)

Comment: Aha, didn't know that there was a PreparingCellForEdit event. But e.Column.GetCellContent(e.Row) returns a ContentPresenter, not a TextBox. So it leaves me with the same problem.

Comment: What is the `ContentPresenter.Content`? I mean what if you search the VisualTree of that `ContentPresenter`?

Comment: It returns null. I believe that it has something to do with the DataTemplate that I'm using in my CellEditingTemplate.