# How to bring cell in edit mode as soon as it gets focus

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Suppose I have a DataGrid. Suppose all the columns are TemplateColumns. When any cell gets focus I want it to go in EditMode.

**What I have tried so far:**

I have created a style for DataGridCell as follows:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="DataGridCell_GotFocus" />
</Style>
```

In the Code-Behind of the Window :

```
private void DataGridCell_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
    if (cell != null && !cell.IsEditing && !cell.IsReadOnly)
    {
        cell.IsEditing = true;
    }
}
```

**Problems in above try :**

I have to single click the cell to bring it in edit mode.

Comment: So, what's your requirement? With single click cell gets focus and goes into edit mode which seems perfect to me. Isn't it?

Comment: No, When I press TAB on a cell the other cell gets focused but does not go into edit mode. I mean I want to bring cell in edit mode as soon as the cell gets focused.

Comment: According to the current behavior I have to press TAB twice to get cell in edit mode.

Comment: Have you define CellEditingTemplate for your TemplateColumn and placed TextBox in there?

Comment: @RohitVats yes i have done exactly as you asked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On focus, cell goes into edit mode but the textBox doesn't have keyboard focus so **next tab  press will be eaten up by textBox** and will get the focus.

As you mentioned you have to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice to move focus to next cell. What you can do is **put focus on TextBox on loaded event**:

*XAML* for dummy element:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Loaded="TextBox_Loaded"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

*Code behind*:

```
private void TextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TextBox).Focus();
}
```

Of course you can move the handler to some base style for all your TextBoxes in dataGrid so you don't have to hook the handler for all cells.

---

In case you don't want to have handler, you can also do that using **`interactivity`** triggers like defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13645028/632337):

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}">
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                <Interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                    <local:TakeFocusAction />
                </Interactivity:EventTrigger>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

and behavior trigger action:

```
public class TakeFocusAction : TriggerAction<UIElement>
{
    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        AssociatedObject.Focus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a trick to make it editable

`BeginEdit()` method brings the current cell into edit mode.

sample

```
    private void DataGridCell_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
        if (cell != null && !cell.IsEditing && !cell.IsReadOnly)
        {
            var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(cell);
            while (parent != null && parent.GetType() != typeof(DataGrid))
            {
                parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
            }
            DataGrid dGrid = parent as DataGrid;
            dGrid.BeginEdit();
        }
    }
```

if you have access to the data grid then finding it may not be necessary

eg

```
    private void DataGridCell_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
        if (cell != null && !cell.IsEditing && !cell.IsReadOnly)
        {
            dGrid.BeginEdit();
        }
    }
```

---

**Update: `FocusManager` trick**

if focus is the only issue you can leverage `FocusManager` by setting `FocusManager.FocusedElement`. give it a try, it works `without any code behind`.

sample

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" 
                     FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

note that I have set the `FocusedElement` to the `TextBox` by binding to self, this will bring the TextBox to focus once loaded (as it enters in edit mode)

Comment: I have access to the datagrid but the result is same

Comment: is the event handler being called? and the `dGrid.BeginEdit()` is executed?